Swift - Codable "Number 2.87 is not representable in Swift"
I have the following struct:
struct CustomerEntries: Codable {
    var date: String
    var customer_rate: Double
    var percentage: Double
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case date
        case customer_rate = "customer-rate"
        case percentage = "percentage-change"
    }
}

I decode JSON using Alamofire's serializingDecodable() such as this:
let response = await AF.request("https://api.xx.com/endpoint", parameters: params, headers: headers)
                .validate()
                .serializingDecodable(CustomerEntries.self)
                .response

It works fine for the first few results (I traced it), and eventually the response fails for a specific return value of 2.87 for customer_rate with the error "Number 2.87 is not representable in Swift".
The JSON returned value is:
"customer-rate": 2.87

I tried decoding to String instead but since the JSON returned value is not enclosed in double quotes, this time the response fails with the error "Expected to decode String but found number instead".
Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Interesting. I would have expected a keyNotFound error. And – although unrelated  to the issue – please don't use snake_case variable names in Swift.

good catch @DávidPásztor - thanks. that was a typo, edited the Question.

Possibly related: Decoding JSON fails on iOS 17: “Number <…> is not representable in Swift”

Probably, but it doesn't help me as such. Tried casting to Float, Int, even JSON (SwiftyJSON) and then extract its doubleValue, they all fail. I tried adding init(from decoder: Decoder) and used container.decode(...)....  keeps failing.

Please check if the dot in the numeric JSON value is really 0x2e (decimal 35). Decoding a simple floating point number like this must not fail.
